# mysql query with count calculation on the same table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a Member table

```
id | parentid | name
1           1      a
2           1      x
3           1      c
4           2      d
5           3      e
6           3      f
7           4      g
```

I need a query to show a list of members and  be sorted from the highest number of people they are parent to them so the answer will be

```
id | name  |rank
1      a     3
3      c     2
2      b     0
4      d     0
5      f     0
6      g     0
7      h     0
```

Comment: Some code is required to get an answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inline view to calculate a `rank` value, and use an outer join operation to match that to the detail rows.

For example, something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , IFNULL(r.rank,0) AS `rank`
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT c.parentid
              , COUNT(1) AS `rank`
           FROM mytable c
          GROUP BY c.parentid
       ) r
    ON r.parentid = t.id
 ORDER BY `rank` DESC, t.id ASC
```